# Javascript form automatic calculation through several rows

Tags: javascript, html

Friends
I am trying to automate quoting form so I do not have to calculate all sub totals etc.

I have here form:

```js
function multiply2(element) {
var rowCount=element.id;
var index=rowCount.lastIndexOf("_");
rowCount=rowCount.substring(index+1);

a2 = Number(document.getElementById('quantity_'+rowCount).value);
b2 = Number(document.getElementById('each_'+rowCount).value);
c2 = a2 * b2;
document.getElementById('mc_gross_'+rowCount).value = parseFloat(Math.round(c2 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
function total20() {
 t1 = Number(document.getElementById('mc_gross_1').value);
 t2 = Number(document.getElementById('mc_gross_2').value);
 sh = Number(document.getElementById('mc_shipping').value);
  tax = Number(document.getElementById('tax').value);
 t21 = t1 + t2 + sh + tax;
 document.getElementById('mc_gross').value = parseFloat(Math.round(t21 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
 }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="">
  <div>
    total: <input type="text" size="4" class="form-control" name="mc_gross" id="mc_gross" onKeyUp="total20()">
   </div> 
   
   <div>
    tax:<input type="text" class="form-control" size="3" name="tax" id="tax" value="10">
    shipping:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mc_shipping" id="mc_shipping" size="3" value="30">
   </div>
   <br>
   /* row 1 of the data entry */
   <div>
name 1<input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" name="item_name1" id="item_name_1" value="Ipad Air" > 
 qty 1<input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity1" id="quantity_1" onKeyUp="multiply2(this)" size="2" value="2">
 each 1<input class="form-control" type="text" name="each1" id="each_1" onKeyUp="multiply2(this)" size="2" value="5.00">
 sub total 1<input class="form-control" type="text" size="5" name="mc_gross_1" id="mc_gross_1" readonly>
 </div> <br>
   /* row 2 of the data entry */
   <div>
name 2<input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" name="item_name2" id="item_name_2" value="Ipad Air" > 
 qty 2<input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity2" id="quantity_2" onKeyUp="multiply2(this)" size="2">
 each 2<input class="form-control" type="text" name="each2" id="each_2" onKeyUp="multiply2(this)" size="2">
 sub total 2<input class="form-control" type="text" size="5" name="mc_gross_2" id="mc_gross_2" readonly>
 </div>
   /* then row 3 - up to number 20 row of the data entry */
</form>
```

When I do the quoting - I enter name, qty, price each and then calculate qty time each and I get the total of one row,

Then do all needed rows and calculate all subtotals - then add shipping to the number then calculate sales tax of 6% and I have a grand total of the quote.

How to do all the calculations for all of the rows is some kind of loop.

I tried something like: Javascript

```
function multiply1() {
  a1 = Number(document.getElementById('quantity1').value);
  b1 = Number(document.getElementById('each1').value);
  c1 = a1 * b1;
  document.getElementById('mc_gross_1').value = parseFloat(Math.round(c1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}

function multiply2() {
  a2 = Number(document.getElementById('quantity2').value);
  b2 = Number(document.getElementById('each2').value);
  c2 = a2 * b2;
  document.getElementById('mc_gross_2').value = parseFloat(Math.round(c2 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);  
}
```

Then another function for a totals but the totals function was not working and all the previous code stopped as well
Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Below the tags you should see "share edit close flag". Click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55284013/edit)

Comment: You should include your javascript code into your snippet.

Comment: It's JavaScript, not Java (they are different things).

Comment: So nobody can help? I know it is a working code but to do it for 20 rows or maybe 60 rows it would be a lot of repeating code - there must ba a way of looping it in some way. Also how about calculation of totals from each row? Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following div:

```
/* row 2 of the data entry */
<div>
name 2<input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" name="item_name2" id="item_name2" value="Ipad Air" > 
 qty 2<input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity2" id="quantity2" onKeyUp="multiply2()" size="2">
 each 2<input class="form-control" type="text" name="each2" id="each2" onKeyUp="multiply2()" size="2">
 sub total 2<input class="form-control" type="text" size="5" name="mc_gross_2" id="mc_gross_2" readonly>
 </div>
```

to:

```
/* row 2 of the data entry */
 <div>
name 2<input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" name="item_name2" id="item_name_2" value="Ipad Air" > 
 qty 2<input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity2" id="quantity_2" onKeyUp="multiply2(this)" size="2">
 each 2<input class="form-control" type="text" name="each2" id="each_2" onKeyUp="multiply2(this)" size="2">
 sub total 2<input class="form-control" type="text" size="5" name="mc_gross_2" id="mc_gross_2" readonly>
 </div>
```

That means all ids format as *name*_*rowcount*.

And then you change the function multiply2 to :

```
function multiply2(element) {
var rowCount=element.id;
var index=rowCount.lastIndexOf("_");
rowCount=rowCount.substring(index+1);

a2 = Number(document.getElementById('quantity_'+rowCount).value);
b2 = Number(document.getElementById('each_'+rowCount).value);
c2 = a2 * b2;
document.getElementById('mc_gross_'+rowCount).value = parseFloat(Math.round(c2 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

The above javascript extract the row count from the id and then append the row count in id field to get the target element.

Comment: Ok so it simplified a little. How about counting all sub totals and adding a shipping to it to make a very grand total for the whole for. How to achieve it?

Comment: do you know how to use jquery?

Comment: I would try in JQuery. Was trying to figure it out how to make total from all of the rows if I have lets say 20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I show the subtotal calculation sample code to you:

```
var mc_gross_all=$("input[id^='mc_gross_']");
var subTotal=0;
for (var i=0;i<mc_gross_all.length;i++)
{
   subTotal+=Number(mc_gross_all[i].value);
}
```